# Connect 4 Javascript Game - Push to lowest circle in column

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ive got this Connect4 game : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lmFJf

What I'd like to do is when I click on any free space/circle in a column, it adds it to the lowest circle/point in the column (just like standard Connect 4 / 4-in-a-row) however I'm having trouble doing this.

I'm not sure if my current setup will allow me to easily do this though...

Thoughts?

Comment: You can ask for algorithms at http://programmers.stackexchange.com not here!

Answer (score 1):

Your click events are tied to the cells. Shouldn't they be tied to the columns instead? Since you can't actually place a piece in a cell that would have an empty space below it.

I think this will greatly simplify your setup.

Each column keeps a record of which pieces it has, like: `RYREEE` (red yellow empty).

---

Also, keep your model in JavaScript. Don't read from the DOM. The DOM should be a view only.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this makes much more sense to tie them to the columns.